# Оператор foreach не работает с переменным типа, как исправить?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть таблица Kontingents в MS SQL 2008. К таблице подключаюсь через Linq to SQL. Контексты и классы создает автоматический. Ищу в базе по номеру студента, нахожу, вывожу о нем информацию во вью. Теперь рядом хочу вывести всех студентов которые вместе с ним учится в одной группе. Что-то не получается
Контроллер:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(Kontingents model)
{
    model = dbk.Kontingents.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IIN == User.Identity.Name);
    var  model2 = dbk.Kontingents.Where(s => s.GRUPPA ==model.GRUPPA).FirstOrDefault(); //<==Вот так ищу одногрупников, правильно?
    return View(model);
}
```

Вью:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication11.Models.Kontingents>
@foreach (WebApplication11.Models.Kontingents k in Model)
{
}
```

> Здесь в слове "Model" ошибка "Оператор foreach не работает с переменным типа WebApplication11.Models.Kontingents так как WebApplication11.Models.Kontingents не содержит открытого определения для GetEnumerator

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` возвращает первое (одно) значение или значение по умолчанию (null), если результат выборки пуст. У вас там нет массива, который  вы ожидаете во модели представления (`IEnumerable<,,,,>`). Вам нужно `where(...).toList()` или `toArray` чтобы выбрать все результаты, а не только единственный первый

Comment: Спасибо! А как можно передать результаты двух запросов в один вью? например var current = dbk.Kontingents.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IIN == User.Identity.Name); будет в одном блоке div а результаты group1 в другом. Сейчас я результаты первого запроса передал через ViewBag а второй как обычно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаем рабочий код

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var current = dbk.Kontingents.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IIN == User.Identity.Name);
    var group1 = dbk.Kontingents.Where(s => s.GRUPPA == current.GRUPPA).ToList(); 
    return View(group1);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` - берёт первый элемент удовлетворяющий условию
`Where` - берёт все элементы удовлетворяющие условию
`ToList` - превращает в список

Почитать про **Linq** - [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php).